# A following models with django neomodel

Tags: python, django, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I use from neo4j database and django-neomodel,
I want to implement a Following system for my users and write this model for users:

```
class UserNode(StructuredNode):
    user_id = IntegerProperty(required=True, index=True)
    follow = RelationshipTo('UserNode','FOLLOW')

    def get_followers(self):
        results, metadata = self.cypher("START a=node({self}) MATCH a<-[:FOLLOW]-(b) RETURN b");
        return [self.__class__.inflate(row[0]) for row in results]

    def get_following(self):
        results, metadata = self.cypher("START a=node({self}) MATCH b-[:FOLLOW]->(a) RETURN b");
        return [self.__class__.inflate(row[0]) for row in results]

    def follow_person(self, user_id):
        import datetime
        from django.utils.timezone import utc

        followed_user = self.index.get(user_id=user_id)
        self.follow.connect(followed_user, {'time': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))})
        self.save()
        followed_user.save()
```

Do you think my UserNode models for following system is a good model?

and a problem with this models occoured! 
when i run this code:

```
a = UserNode.index.get(user_id=200)
b = UserNode.index.get(user_id=201)
c = UserNode.index.get(user_id=202)

a.follow_person(201)
b.follow_person(200)

print a.get_followers(), a.get_following()
```

output is two empty list. why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi author of neomodel here.

There is no need to save in the follow_person method.
Which version of neomodel are you using? The following code worked for me:

```
class UserNode(StructuredNode):                                                                                                                                                                        
    user_id = IntegerProperty(required=True, index=True)
    follow = RelationshipTo('UserNode', 'FOLLOW')

    def get_followers(self):
        results, metadata = self.cypher("START a=node({self}) MATCH a<-[:FOLLOW]-(b) RETURN b")
        return [self.__class__.inflate(row[0]) for row in results]

    def get_following(self):
        results, metadata = self.cypher("START a=node({self}) MATCH b-[:FOLLOW]->(a) RETURN b")
        return [self.__class__.inflate(row[0]) for row in results]

    def follow_person(self, user_id):
        followed_user = self.index.get(user_id=user_id)
        self.follow.connect(followed_user, {'time': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())})

u1 = UserNode(user_id=1).save()
u2 = UserNode(user_id=2).save()

u1.follow_person(2)
u2.follow_person(1)
print "User 1 follows {}".format(u1.get_following())
print "User 1's followers {}".format(u1.get_followers())
```

You may also want to consider defining two separate relationship managers for out coming and incoming, this means you don't need to write cypher queries:

```
class UserNode(StructuredNode):
    user_id = IntegerProperty(required=True, index=True)
    following = RelationshipTo('UserNode', 'FOLLOW')
    followers = RelationshipFrom('UserNode', 'FOLLOW')

    def follow_person(self, user_id):
        followed_user = self.index.get(user_id=user_id)
        self.follow.connect(followed_user, {'time': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())})

print "User 1 follows {}".format(u1.following.all())
print "User 1's followers {}".format(u1.followers.all())
```

Hope this helps! Feel free to drop me an email if you any more issues.